# Is it possible to downgrade to cgroup v1 for docker desktop on osx?

Tags: docker, macos

I found my docker use `cgroup v2`, but some tools require to run with `cgroup v1`, will it possible to downgrade to v1? Is there a config parameter for `deamon.json` ?

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.8.2)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.5.1)
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc., 0.6.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.17.0)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 62
 Server Version: 20.10.14
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 3df54a852345ae127d1fa3092b95168e4a88e2f8
 runc version: v1.0.3-0-gf46b6ba
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.10.104-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 9.952GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: ZWVT:2FQD:VLYG:LJNP:FTMD:43CI:TZGO:ZQMC:RAES:OXO2:6JFH:POXZ
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 4):

I find a workaround in the docker desktop release notes:

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#bug-fixes-and-minor-changes-20

> Added a deprecated option to settings.json: "deprecatedCgroupv1": true, which switches the Linux environment back to cgroups v1. If your software requires cgroups v1, you should update it to be compatible with cgroups v2. Although cgroups v1 should continue to work, it is likely that some future features will depend on cgroups v2. It is also possible that some Linux kernel bugs will only be fixed with cgroups v2.

You can find the settings.json in the "$HOME/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json"